# Soap error: "looks like we got no XML document"

Tags: php, xml, soap

I check the difference bettwen a call who work simulating soap with curl request which work here is the xml that work:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://service.test.com/">
    <soapenv:Header/>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <ser:DoItdoItRequest1>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </ser:DoItdoItRequest1>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I change my code using SoapClient to be more clean than emulating a curl request, but my server return me:

```
looks like we got no XML document
```

When debugging I get from client->__getLastRequest()

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://service.test.com/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:DoItdoItRequest1>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </ns1:DoItdoItRequest1>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

The only difference seems to be:

```
<ser:DoItdoItRequest1>
```

against

```
<ns1:DoItdoItRequest1>
```

Do you know how to change this ns1: to a ser: with SoapClient ? an option maybe ? 
I can't find helpful help about that...

Regards.

Comment: The difference is the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`.

Comment: There are quite a few differences - the second one has loads of hyphens in elements (`SOAP-ENV` as opposed to `soapenv`). Also no `<soapenv:Header/>`

Comment: thx for the tips... will try with SOAP-ENV.